# why hashmap doesn't return null in here

Tags: java, hashmap

Hello I am studying for OCP exam and I have a doubt regarding hashmaps. In here I have replaced my first key value (firstStudent, "1") pair with (thirdStudent, "3")

```
package hashmapexam;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HashMapExam {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student firstStudent = new Student("Rob");
        Student secondStudent = new Student("Catlin");
        Student thirdStudent = new Student("Rob");

        Map <Student,String> students = new HashMap<>();

        students.put(firstStudent, "1");
        students.put(secondStudent, "2");
        students.put(thirdStudent, "3");

        System.out.println("Size of the Map : " + students.size());

        System.out.println(students.get(firstStudent));
        System.out.println(students.get(secondStudent));
        System.out.println(students.get(thirdStudent));
    }
}
```

---

```
package hashmapexam;

class Student{

    String name;

    public Student(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(o instanceof Student && ((Student)o).getName().equals(this.getName())){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return name.length();
    }
}
```

I get the following output

> Size of the Map : 2
>
> 3
>
> 2
>
> 3

it seems they have been replaced correctly since the size of the map is 2. but how does it retrieve the value "3" using both firstStudent and thirdStudent Keys? doesn't firstStudent key get replaced by thirdStudent?

Comment: you should get output `Size of the Map : 3`

Comment: No I am getting 2 :o Tried it several times

Comment: @Nitesh Why do you think so?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I executed the same code on my machine and it gives size as 3

Comment: @NiteshVirani You're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`firstStudent` and `thirdStudent` are `equal`. This means that you can use either reference as a key to get the corresponding value.

By the way, using the `length` of a `String` is a poor idea for a `hashCode` method because it will cause lots of different common names to have the same `hashCode`. It's better to use the `hashCode` of the `String`.

Comment: does that means hashmap contains two keys referring to same value? yes inefficacy of String.length() was mentioned in the book I am using to study, this is just a simple program I wrote to understand how hashmap works

Comment: @Paul Boddington i agree ... using String.length as the hascode is not a good idea. Using String.hashcode of member 'name' would work.  Otherwise implementing a good hashcode Method can be quite tricky. HashCodeBuilder from Apache-Commons is a good alternative to implementing HashCode on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Because hash maps (like the name implies) use the key's hashes to place the values into it's buckets. In your case, your `Student` class implements the `equals` and `hashcode` method, where `firstStudent`, and `thirdStudent` both return the same hash; therefore, you have 2 values in your map, and retrieving either (`firstStudent` or `thirdStudent`) will return the same value; `3`, since `thirdStudent` replaces the value `1` set by `firstStudent`, as they both have the same hash value (**edit**) and are considered equal.

#### Update

```
students.put(firstStudent, "1");
// map size: 1
students.put(secondStudent, "2");
// map size: 2
students.put(thirdStudent, "3");
// map size: 2 (replaced first inserted value)
```

In essence

```
boolean b = students.get(firstStudent).equals(students.get(thirdStudent));
// b==true since firstStudent.equals(thirdStudent)==true
```

Comment: Hash does not decide identity in a HashMap. Collision on hash is perfectly allowed and normal (otherwise, there won't be buckets only slots). The op's problem is with the `equals()` method.

Comment: No, he's asking why `firstStudent` is not returning `null`. And I have explained why; because `firstStudent` and `thirdStudent` both return the same hash, so they both access the same bucket.

Comment: @billc.cn I am not arguing about collisions; values in a Map are stored in an array, where value indexes are determined by the hash of it's key. I will not go into the details of such implementation, but suffice to say that this has nothing to do with the OP's question, and my answer is not wrong; since borth `firstStudent` and `thirdStudent` have the same hash... **AND** are considered `equal` by name, then either of the key will access the same bucket to retrieve the value. There's nothing wrong in my answer.

Comment: But accessing the same bucket does not mean anything if `equals()` did not make them equal. You can have a class that returns a constant for `hashcode()` and `HashMap` would still work. However, if `Student.equals()` always return `false`, then `HashMap` will not be able to return values even for keys inside the map regardless of the hashcode.

Comment: @billc.cn did you read my answer? I am citing that since his `Student` class borth implements `equals` *and* `hashcode` ....

Comment: @billc.cn there, I added 4 words in the first paragraph to make it clearer.

Comment: I have never said your answer is wrong. It's simply misleading. You revealed an implementation detail (hashes are used to select buckets), which seems to suggest it has something to do with this "unexpected behaviour". And a novice can easily be mislead to believe if you can change `hashcode` implementation, `students.get(firstStudent)` may magically return `null` (which it wouldn't). A map that is implemented without buckets (e.g. skip list) would behave exactly the same way, so why burden the poor op with the concepts of buckets?

Comment: @billc.cn I'm not the one to put a burden on implementation details. I am merely simplifying the answer into something even a novice can understand. I would not go into a full-length answer since the question is very specific. Perhaps mentioning "buckets" may be misleading, however it *is* accurate in this case and helps explaining, trivially, what's going on under the hood for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your `equals()` method is saying any `Student` instance with the same `name` is equal. `HashMap` use this equality in its operations, so

```
students.put(thirdStudent, "3");
```

will replace the entry created by

```
students.put(firstStudent, "1");
```

as `thirdStudent` and `firstStudent` are equivalent keys.

Similarly, `students.get(firstStudent)` and `students.get(thirdStudent)` return the same value as the key used are equivalent.

(Of course, for hashing data structures, this relies on a correct implementation of `hashCode`.)

Another example:

```
new Integer(1) != new Integer(1)
(new Integer(1)).equals(new Integer(1))
(new Integer(1)).hashcode() == (new Integer(1)).hashcode()
```

and this is why `Integer`s can be used as keys in `HashMap`s.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Student` Object which is `firstStudent` and `thirdStudent` are **equal** and there **hashCode** is also return the same value i.e. 3 because of **overriding** the `hashCode` in Student Class which intern return the length of the String i.e.

```
@Override
public int hashCode(){
    return name.length();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**in put method of hashmap :**

> If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value
>   is replaced by the specified value. **A map m is said to contain a
>   mapping for a key k if and only if map.containsKey(key) would return
>   true. and map.containsKey(key) returns true if and only if this map contains a mapping for a key k such that key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k)**

in your case you have first added "firstStudent" with value "1" and than you have added "thirdStudent" but as thirdStudent.equals(firstStudent) so value of firstStudent will be replaced by "3"

**in get method of hashmap :**

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if
>   this map contains no mapping for the key. More formally, ***if this
>   map contains a mapping from a key k to a value v such that (key==null
>   ? k==null : key.equals(k)), then this method returns v; otherwise it
>   returns null.***

in your case firstStudent and thirdStudent refers to same value

Answer (score 0):

students.put(firstStudent, "1");

Map : ***Rob -> 1***

```
students.put(secondStudent, "2");
```

Map : ***Rob -> 1*** and
      ***Catlin -> 2***

```
students.put(thirdStudent, "3");
```

Map : ***Rob -> 3***     (third Student is also named 'Rob') 
      ***Catlin -> 2***

So if you access the Map with 'Rob' you get '3' since the second Put with 'Rob' replaced the value '1' with '3'. Since the first and
the third student are both called 'Rob' and equals only compares by Name and both have the same hashcode they are the same keys from the point of view of the HashMap. **So the Map contains only two Entries after the three 'put' operations.**

So you get Rob -> 3 Catlin -> 2 Rob -> 3 ... the sequence 3,2,3

Comment: Yes my question is how does hashmap retrieve the value "3" using both firstStudent and thirdStudent keys? why doesn't students.get(firstStudent) return null since that key has been replace with thirdStudent?

Comment: @LakshithaRanasinghe Because if you access the Map with a key the map will first calculate the Keys Hashcode and use that to retrieve a list (called bucket) with all objects with the same hashcode that have been put into the map before. after that the Map searches that list for the key. it compares the list entries using 'equals'. So if you put in two Students both named 'Rob' the second 'put' replaces the value this key is mapped to with the new value.

Comment: @LakshithaRanasinghe "why doesn't students.get(firstStudent) return null since that key has been replace with thirdStudent" -> because firstStudent and secondStudent are the same from the point of view of the map.

Answer (score 0):

The error: `firstStudent` and `thirdStudent` are the same object.

"the same" means that they are equal in perspective of java.

The reason: Strings with equal content are equal and your students 
are both called "rob".

Your hashMap puts the two students into the same bucket, because the names(=keys) are equal and therefore both give you the output `3`